# Shiny App not printing prediction

Tags: r, shiny

I have this code i'm testing out that is to output the prediction based on the inputs in Shiny. The input variables are printed fine in the Main Panel (I re-printed the values the user entered). However, the prediction value is not being printed. Please see my code below. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(shiny)



ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("Prediction of Activity in Each Bank"),
sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("explain1",
               label =h4("Bank"),choices = c('CBN','Access Bank Nigeria Plc','Diamond Bank Plc','Ecobank Nigeria Ltd'), selected = 'CBN'),
  selectInput("explain2",
               label =h4("Type"),choices = c('Currency Received (Note Boxes)', 'Currency Withdrawn (Note Boxes)'),selected = 'Currency Withdrawn (Note Boxes)'),
submitButton('Predict')
  ),  
mainPanel(h3('Result of Prediction',
             h4('You Entered for Bank'),
             verbatimTextOutput('inputValue1'),
             h4('You Entered for Transaction Type'),
             verbatimTextOutput("inputValue2"),
             h4('The Result of the prediction is'),
             verbatimTextOutput('predcition1')
             ))
  )
 ))






  server = shinyServer(function(input, output){

 output$inputValue1 = renderPrint({input$explain1}) 
 output$inputValue2 = renderPrint({input$explain2})
 output$prediction1 = renderPrint({
data = read.csv('C:/Users/rose.anwuri/Documents/Data Analysis/Datasets/Test          for R.csv')
model1 = lm(Activity.Count ~ Transacction.Type+Organization, data = data )
test = data.frame(paste(input$explain1), paste(input$explain2))
names(test) = c('Organization', 'Transacction.Type')
toString(round(predict(model1, test),2))
  })
})


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hi, what is your output of your 'toString(round(predict(model1, test),2))' command?

Comment: You have a typo in the server it is prediction1 and on the ui it is predcition1

Comment: Aaron Thanks it worked!